# Unable to Retrieve data from Firebase in my java android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Home.java class

```
package com.example.rsvpea;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.rsvpea.Models.UploadEventModel;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ImageButton home;
    public static ImageButton bookings;
    public static ImageButton profile;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        home = findViewById(R.id.home);
        bookings = findViewById(R.id.myBookings);
        profile = findViewById(R.id.myProfile);
        BottomNavBar buttonClickListenerHome = new BottomNavBar(home);
        BottomNavBar buttonClickListenerBookings = new BottomNavBar(bookings);
        BottomNavBar buttonClickListenerProfile = new BottomNavBar(profile);

        ArrayList<TimelineCardContent> timelineCardContents = new ArrayList<>();

        RecyclerView timeline = findViewById(R.id.timelineRecyclerView);
        timeline.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database.getReference().child("Event List").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    //String img = itemSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                    //String eventTitle = itemSnapshot.child("eventTitle").getValue(String.class);
                    UploadEventModel temp = itemSnapshot.getValue(UploadEventModel.class);
                    timelineCardContents.add(new TimelineCardContent(temp.getImage(), temp.getEventTitle()));
                }
                Log.d("FirebaseData", "Data retrieved: " + timelineCardContents.size() + " items");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RecycleContentAdapter adapter = new RecycleContentAdapter(this, timelineCardContents);
        System.out.println(timelineCardContents);
        timeline.setAdapter(adapter);
        home.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListenerHome);
        profile.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListenerProfile);
        bookings.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListenerBookings);
        findViewById(R.id.uploadnewevent).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, UploadActivity.class);
            Home.this.startActivity(intent);
        });


    }
}
```

adapter class

```
package com.example.rsvpea;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecycleContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<TimelineCardContent> arrContent;
    RecycleContentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TimelineCardContent> arrContent){
        this.context=context;
        this.arrContent=arrContent;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.timeline_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TimelineCardContent content = arrContent.get(position);
        //holder.img.setImageResource(arrContent.get(position).img);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(content.img)
                .into(holder.img);
        holder.title.setText(arrContent.get(position).title);
        holder.moreDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MoreDetails.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrContent.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView img;
        Button moreDetailsButton;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            moreDetailsButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreDetails);

        }
    }
}
```

Here's my event model class

```
package com.example.rsvpea.Models;

public class UploadEventModel {
    private String eventTitle, Desc, date, venue, image;

    public UploadEventModel(String eventTitle, String desc, String date, String venue, String image) {
        this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
        this.Desc = desc;
        this.date = date;
        this.venue = venue;
        this.image = image;
    }
    public UploadEventModel(){}

    public String getEventTitle() {
        return eventTitle;
    }

    public void setEventTitle(String eventTitle) {
        this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return Desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        Desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

in my logcat it shows ArrayList is empty

> 2023-11-06 14:27:36.006 23637-23637 FirebaseData            com.example.rsvpea                   D  Data retrieved: 0

here's the JSON file:

```
{
  "Events List": {
    "5 Nov 2023 20:43:57": {
      "date": "29 feb 2024",
      "desc": "birthday party for a batak",
      "eventTitle": "Batak Bday",
      "image": "url",
      "venue": "TMA Pai"
    },
    "5 Nov 2023 23:12:29": {
      "date": "40 feb 2024 ",
      "desc": "event description sample",
      "eventTitle": "new event",
      "image": "url",
      "venue": "tma pai"
    },
    "6 Nov 2023 00:28:28": {
      "date": "hhhs",
      "desc": "hshsh",
      "eventTitle": "hsha",
      "image": "url"
    }
  },
  "Users": {
    "cN0Z4YQEeoXPQKYH0lYxQegpfFE2": {
      "mail": "ayu@awsm.ayu",
      "password": "hello123",
      "userName": "ayu"
    }
  }
}
```

app runs without giving any error but shows empty recycler view.
any help?

Instead of using model i tried doing it manually like this but that didnt work either

```
String img = itemSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
String eventTitle = itemSnapshot.child("eventTitle").getValue(String.class);
```

here are my database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,  // 2023-12-4
    ".write": true,  // 2023-12-4
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Just added the jason file. any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces this output `Data retrieved: 0`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added it after the loop to check if anything is being retrieved, i am simply checking the arraylist size 

` Log.d("FirebaseData", "Data retrieved: " + timelineCardContents.size() + " items"); `
this is the line

Comment: If you try to log the value of `snapshot.getChildrenCount()`, what is the output?

Comment: when i manually insert a new element in the array list by using any random url and sample title it works just fine so i think adapter class(RecycleContentAdapter) shouldnt have any issues

Comment: @AlexMamo Children retrieved: 0 items
` Log.d("getChildren", "Children retrieved: " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " items");`
used this right after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closer at your code and database schema, I saw that the problem comes from the following line of code:

```
database.getReference().child("Event List").addValueEventListener(/* ... /*);
```

Why? Because the node in the database is called "Events List" and not "Event List". See there is an `s` missing. So to solve this, please use the correct reference:

```
database.getReference().child("Events List").addValueEventListener(/* ... /*);
//
```

Comment: thanks a bunch man I've spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to fix this. you're a lifesaver (Sorry i cant upvote because my account is new)